# Inconsistent results with the same query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that only sums and retrieves data with SELECT statements ( by using other stored procedures ). There is no update or insert at all in these stored procedures and of course all of involved data are static. This main stored procedure returns double. The weird thing is if I execute it a couple of times, usually after 3 - 4 times, the results are different from the first 3 - 4 results then it stays like that although I keep executing it.

I thought its because of computer precision problem, but the results are still under 1 million and the difference can be up to 4 to 8.

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qtDyjufU

Comment: Hello Mideel and welcome to SO. Check out the guidance on asking a question with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise it is virtually impossible to give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely here:

```
IF (FOUND) THEN
  vSaldo := vRecSearchSaldoAwal.balance;
  RAISE NOTICE 'Balance Adjustment: %', vRecSearchSaldoAwal.balance;

  ...

  SELECT (_dateStart - INTERVAL '1 day'), NULL, NULL, vSaldo, TX_STOCKADJ, 'Saldo Sebelumnya' INTO vRetval;

  RETURN NEXT vRetval;

ELSEIF (NOT FOUND) THEN
  vSaldo := SumQtyBeginningBal(_idproduct, _idGudang);

  ...
```

The phrase `ELSEIF (NOT FOUND) THEN` looks at the `FOUND` value **which has been set by the last `SELECT` statement inside the IF/IFELSE block**. You probably want to put a simple `ELSE` instead.